# How to use classes in Python (Classes are not working in my code)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, calculator, calculation

I made a code then decided to split it up into a GUI class and a logic class but now that I have done that the code does not function after I made the two classes, it works without the classes but I am trying to make it work with classes. if someone could fix this problem I will be so grateful. Any help will be kindly appreciated thank you.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI:
    notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(frame1, text='Length')
    frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(frame2, text='Weight')
    frame3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
    notebook.add(frame3, text='Temperature')
    notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")
    #======================================================================
    entry = Entry(frame1)
    entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

    label = Label(frame1, relief='groove', width=20, text='')
    label.grid(row=0, column=3)

    options1 = ['mm', 'cm', 'm', 'km', 'Inches', 'Feet', 'Yards', 'Miles']

    var1 = tk.StringVar(frame1)
    var1.set(options1[0])

    dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(frame1, var1, options1[0], options1[1], options1[2], options1[3], options1[4], options1[5], options1[6], options1[7])
    dropdown1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    var2 = tk.StringVar(frame1)
    var2.set(options1[0])

    dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(frame1, var2, options1[0], options1[1], options1[2], options1[3], options1[4], options1[5], options1[6], options1[7])
    dropdown2.grid(row=1, column=3)

    equal_button = Button(frame1, text='=', command=Length_Error) 
    equal_button.grid(row=1, column=5)
    #======================================================================
    weight_entry = Entry(frame2)
    weight_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

    weight_label = Label(frame2, relief='groove', width=20, text='')
    weight_label.grid(row=0, column=3)

    options2 = ['Grams', 'Kilograms', 'Ounces', 'Pounds', 'Tonnes']

    weight_var1 = tk.StringVar(frame2)
    weight_var1.set(options2[0])

    dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(frame2, weight_var1, options2[0], options2[1], options2[2], options2[3], options2[4])
    dropdown1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    weight_var2 = tk.StringVar(frame1)
    weight_var2.set(options2[0])

    dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(frame2, weight_var2, options2[0], options2[1], options2[2], options2[3], options2[4])
    dropdown2.grid(row=1, column=3)

    weight_equal_button = Button(frame2, text='=', command=Weight_Error) 
    weight_equal_button.grid(row=1, column=5)
    #======================================================================
    temp_entry = Entry(frame3)
    temp_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)

    temp_label = Label(frame3, relief='groove', width=20, text='')
    temp_label.grid(row=0, column=3)

    options3 = ['Celsius', 'Fahrenheit', 'Kelvin']

    temp_var1 = tk.StringVar(frame3)
    temp_var1.set(options3[0])

    temp_dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(frame3, temp_var1, options3[0], options3[1], options3[2])
    temp_dropdown1.grid(row=1, column=0)

    temp_var2 = tk.StringVar(frame3)
    temp_var2.set(options3[0])

    temp_dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(frame3, temp_var2, options3[0], options3[1], options3[2])
    temp_dropdown2.grid(row=1, column=3)

    temp_equal_button = Button(frame3, text='=', command=Temperature_Error) 
    temp_equal_button.grid(row=1, column=5)
    #======================================================================

class logic:
    #======================================================================
    def Length_Error(*args):
        try:
            v = float(entry.get())       
        except ValueError:
            label['text']=('Enter Valid Input')
        else:
            Length_converter()
    #======================================================================
    def Weight_Error(*args):
        try:
            v = float(weight_entry.get())
        except ValueError:
            weight_label['text']=('Enter Valid Input')
        else:
            Weight_converter()
    #======================================================================
    def Temperature_Error(*args):
        try:
            v = float(temp_entry.get())
        except ValueError:
            temp_label['text']=('Enter Valid Input')
        else:
            Temperature_converter()
    #======================================================================
    def Length_converter(*args):
        v = float(entry.get())
        metre_dict = dict(mm= 0.001, cm= 0.01, m= 1, km= 1000, Inches= 0.0254, Feet= 0.3048, Yards= 0.9144, Miles= 1609.344)
        M = v * metre_dict[var1.get()]
        k = M / metre_dict[var2.get()]
        label['text']=k
    #======================================================================
    def Weight_converter(*args):
        v = float(weight_entry.get())
        weight_dict = dict(Grams= 1, Kilograms= 1000, Ounces= 28.34952313, Pounds= 453.59237, Tonnes= 1000000)
        M = v * weight_dict[weight_var1.get()]
        k = M / weight_dict[weight_var2.get()]
        weight_label['text']=k
    #======================================================================
    def Temperature_converter(*args):
        temp_dict = dict(Fahrenheit=(1/1.8, -32/1.8), Celsius=(1, 0), Kelvin=(1, -273.15))
        x, y= temp_dict[temp_var1.get()]
        cels = float(temp_entry.get()) * x + y
        x, y = temp_dict[temp_var2.get()]
        answer = (cels - y) / x
        temp_label['text']=answer

        root.mainloop
```

Comment: if you created classes then you have to create instances to use them ie. `x = Logic()` , `x.Length_converter(...)`. Class should also have variable `self` to have access to `itself` and variables created in different method in class. It is good to create widget in method in Class, not directly in class.

Comment: if you split into two classe then don't use widgets in logic. Logic should get value as argument and use `return` to send result.

Answer (score 1):

If you create class for logic then it should get arguments and return result and not use widgets. Button should run function which get values from widgets and use them with Logic, and latere get result and put to widget.

This class Logic doesn't have to remeber values so I think method can be static.

In class  we put code rateher in methods and we use `self.` to have access to the same variables in different methods in class

```
#### from tkinter import *  <-- not preferred

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):  # <-- init class

        root = tk.Tk()  # <-- main window

        notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
        frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

        notebook.add(frame1, text='Length')
        frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

        notebook.add(frame2, text='Weight')
        frame3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)

        notebook.add(frame3, text='Temperature')
        notebook.pack(expand=1, fill="both")

        #======================================================================

        self.entry = tk.Entry(frame1)  # <-- self. / tk.
        self.entry.grid(row=0, column=0)  # <-- self.

        self.label = tk.Label(frame1, relief='groove', width=20, text='')  # <-- self. / tk.
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=3)  # <-- self.

        options1 = ['mm', 'cm', 'm', 'km', 'Inches', 'Feet', 'Yards', 'Miles']

        self.var1 = tk.StringVar(frame1)  # <-- self.
        self.var1.set(options1[0])  # <-- self.

        dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(frame1, self.var1, *options1)  # <-- self. / *options1
        dropdown1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.var2 = tk.StringVar(frame1)  # <-- self.
        self.var2.set(options1[0])  # <-- self.

        dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(frame1, self.var2, *options1)  # <-- self. / *options1
        dropdown2.grid(row=1, column=3)

        equal_button = tk.Button(frame1, text='=', command=self.convert_length)   # <-- tk. / function in GUI
        equal_button.grid(row=1, column=5)

        #======================================================================

        self.weight_entry = tk.Entry(frame2)  # <-- self. / tk.
        self.weight_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)  # <-- self.

        self.weight_label = tk.Label(frame2, relief='groove', width=20, text='')  # <-- self. / tk.
        self.weight_label.grid(row=0, column=3)  # <-- self.

        options2 = ['Grams', 'Kilograms', 'Ounces', 'Pounds', 'Tonnes']

        self.weight_var1 = tk.StringVar(frame2)  # <-- self.
        self.weight_var1.set(options2[0])  # <-- self.

        dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(frame2, self.weight_var1, *options2)  # <-- self. / *options2
        dropdown1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.weight_var2 = tk.StringVar(frame1)  # <-- self.
        self.weight_var2.set(options2[0])  # <-- self.

        dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(frame2, self.weight_var2, *options2)  # <-- self. / *options2
        dropdown2.grid(row=1, column=3)

        weight_equal_button = tk.Button(frame2, text='=', command=self.convert_weight)  # <-- tk. / function in GUI
        weight_equal_button.grid(row=1, column=5)

        #======================================================================

        self.temp_entry = tk.Entry(frame3)  # <-- self. / tk.
        self.temp_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)  # <-- self.

        self.temp_label = tk.Label(frame3, relief='groove', width=20, text='')  # <-- self. / tk.
        self.temp_label.grid(row=0, column=3)  # <-- self.

        options3 = ['Celsius', 'Fahrenheit', 'Kelvin']

        self.temp_var1 = tk.StringVar(frame3)  # <-- self.
        self.temp_var1.set(options3[0])  # <-- self.

        temp_dropdown1 = tk.OptionMenu(frame3, self.temp_var1, *options3)  # <-- self. / *options3
        temp_dropdown1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.temp_var2 = tk.StringVar(frame3)  # <-- self.
        self.temp_var2.set(options3[0])  # <-- self.

        temp_dropdown2 = tk.OptionMenu(frame3, self.temp_var2, *options3)  # <-- self. / *options3
        temp_dropdown2.grid(row=1, column=3)

        temp_equal_button = tk.Button(frame3, text='=', command=self.convert_temp)   # <-- tk. / function in GUI
        temp_equal_button.grid(row=1, column=5)

        #======================================================================

        root.mainloop()  # <--- () , it starts window

    # <-- functions assigned to buttons

    def convert_length(self):
        var1 = self.var1.get()
        var2 = self.var2.get()

        try:
            value = float(self.entry.get())       
        except ValueError:
            self.label['text'] = 'Enter Valid Input'
            return

        try:
            self.label['text'] = Converter.convert_length(value, var1, var2)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.label['text'] = 'Exception: {}'.format(ex)

    def convert_weight(self):
        var1 = self.weight_var1.get()
        var2 = self.weight_var2.get()

        try:
            value = float(self.weight_entry.get())       
        except ValueError:
            self.weight_label['text'] = 'Enter Valid Input'
            return

        try:
            self.weight_label['text'] = Converter.convert_weight(value, var1, var2)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.weight_label['text'] = 'Exception: {}'.format(ex)

    def convert_temp(self):
        var1 = self.temp_var1.get()
        var2 = self.temp_var2.get()

        try:
            value = float(self.temp_entry.get())       
        except ValueError:
            self.temp_label['text'] = 'Enter Valid Input'
            return

        try:
            self.temp_label['text'] = Converter.convert_temperature(value, var1, var2)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.temp_label['text'] = 'Exception: {}'.format(ex)


class Converter: # <-- UpperCaseName

    @staticmethod
    def convert_length(v, var1, var2):  # <-- lower_case_name / arguments

        metre_dict = dict(mm= 0.001, cm= 0.01, m= 1, km= 1000, Inches= 0.0254, Feet= 0.3048, Yards= 0.9144, Miles= 1609.344)

        M = v * metre_dict[var1]
        k = M / metre_dict[var2]

        return k

    #======================================================================

    @staticmethod
    def convert_weight(v, var1, var2):  # <-- lower_case_name / arguments

        weight_dict = dict(Grams= 1, Kilograms= 1000, Ounces= 28.34952313, Pounds= 453.59237, Tonnes= 1000000)

        M = v * weight_dict[var1]
        k = M / weight_dict[var2]

        return k

    #======================================================================

    @staticmethod
    def convert_temperature(v, var1, var2):  # <-- lower_case_name / arguments

        temp_dict = dict(Fahrenheit=(1/1.8, -32/1.8), Celsius=(1, 0), Kelvin=(1, -273.15))

        x, y= temp_dict[var1]
        cels = v * x + y
        x, y = temp_dict[var2]

        return (cels - y) / x

# --- main ----

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI()
```

Comment: I updated the code I posted which you solved how would you apply what you did to this updated version. By the way mate thanks for the help.

Comment: I added extra functions but not sure how to integrate it with the classes

Comment: as before - Logic shouldn't get value from Entry and should't put result in Label. it should get values in `args` and send result with `return`. `root.mainloop()` should be in GUI, not in Logic. Widgets should be created in `__init__`. GUI should have function assigned to Buttons - and these functions should get value from widgets and use as arguments in Logic's methods. And later functions should get result and put in labels.

Comment: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)  - classes should use `CamelCaseName`, methods should use `lower_case_name`,

Comment: I have looked at the style guide on pep 8 and watched multiple youtube videos and just don't get it. if it is possible could you fix it as you did for the original code so I can understand what you have done line by line. I'm new to coding and your help would be extremely grateful.

Comment: I tried another method but still no luck on how to fix the classes on the updated version of the code I posted.

Comment: you can use [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/) to compare two versions. Now `Logic` (class `Converter`) doesn't use any `Label` or `Entry` so you can use it with different GUI or without GUI in text [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface) or web page.